# How to solve two threads manipulating two collections?

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0

I have two classes, each with a `private static List<int> list`, and methods in each class to manipulate the list, that take the following form:

```
public static void Add(int number)
{
  lock (list)
  {
    Monitor.Pulse(list);

    containers.Add(list);

    Monitor.Wait(list);
  }
}
```

The problem is that if I have two threads, and Thread1 is in the Add() method in Class1 and Thread2 is in the Add() method in Class2, then they each will reach the Wait() method. But because they are in different waiting queues, the Pulse() method won't work (at least, that's what I suspect.) How can I solve this conundrum?

Comment: Can you please describe what you are trying to do? It seems like you might be over-complicating things.

Comment: And the code you posted does not seem correct. What is `containers`? And the parameter `container` is not used anywhere.

Comment: why do you need `Monitor.Pulse` and `Monitor.Wait`? why `lock` is not enought?

Comment: You could look for System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection<T>

Comment: I edited the code so that there's no more container. I want to use a list and not a blockingcollection because it doesn't have one. I use monitor.Pulse() and monitor.Wait() so that it's synchronizing. With the Pulse() and Wait() the output will be Thread1 Thread2 Thread1 Thread2 etc.

What I am trying to do is take from one collection and put it in another collection with two threads.

Answer (score 0):

If they are both sharing the same reference to same underlying list, then it is fine. And if you are trying to use the lock keyword, then you do not need to use the Monitor.wait and Monitor.pulseall, because the compiler does that automatically when it see the lock (...) { }.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET 4, you might want to use Concurrent collections.

[More info on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305.aspx)